# Split a decimal number and a text in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to split a string that contains a decimal number and text characters for ex:

`"30.88H"` into an array containing `30.88` and `H`.

I used the following regex:

```
string[] a = 
   Regex.Matches("30.88H", "([A-Z]+)|([0-9]+)").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```

...But this gives me "30","88" and "H", instead of "30.88" and "H".
Could any one suggest the fix?

Comment: `.` isn’t in `[0-9]`. Try adding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only current issue is that `.` is not in [0-9] but I can see this being a fragile solution depending on the input strings. Can you describe the desired behavior a bit more? Will you ever get H3.88? H3.88H? If so what are you expecting out of it?

If your strings will always be in the same order and format, then adding `.` will get you there. If not, describe the scenario a little more and maybe we can come up with a more suitable solution.

Comment: @Tim - It would be better to avoid asking questions inside an answer. Those are best put as comments under the question.

Comment: Not sure why. I can answer the question exactly as asked and help him 0 because he is not considering all the cases, or I can answer his question , while making sure I ask probing questions in case I can help direct him toward the best solution. Seems like helping the most I can is the better way.

Answer (score 0):

**You may want to try to use the *split* method in RegEx.**

---

> To get the string of numbers, split with this expression

```
[A-Z]+
```

> To get the string of characters, try this expression

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
```

---

You should use the split method in the following format:

```
string expr1 = Regex.Split("30.88H", @"[0-9]+\.[0-9]+"); \\Returns H
string expr2 = Regex.Split("30.88H", @"[A-Z]+"); \\Returns 30.88
```